# TypeError: child.transform is undefined Pixijs Webpack

Tags: pixi.js, adobe-animate

I am developing a game based on pixijs, in which animation is generated using Adobe Animate and Pixi-Animate and all this setup is configured with nodejs 8.11.1 and webpack 4. But when I load my texture on Pixi Animate getting the following errors:

Here is my error what i am getting:

```
    addChild
webpack:///./node_modules/pixi.js/lib/core/display/Container.js?:94:13
<anonymous>
webpack:///./src/index.js?:10:1
./src/index.js
http://localhost:9000/salmon.min.js:2786:1
__webpack_require__
http://localhost:9000/salmon.min.js:20:12
<anonymous>
webpack:///multi_(webpack)-dev-server/client?:2:18
[0]
http://localhost:9000/salmon.min.js:2797:1
__webpack_require__
http://localhost:9000/salmon.min.js:20:12
<anonymous>
http://localhost:9000/salmon.min.js:84:18
<anonymous>
http://localhost:9000/salmon.min.js:1:11
```

My Webpack Configuration is:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  mode:"development",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'salmon.min.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: './index.html'}),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  ],
  devServer:{
      port: 9000,
      compress: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ["source-map-loader"],
        enforce: "pre"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I get same error when I add a Text to the stage